# Postgres function to turn regexp_matches SETOF result into an ARRAY

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I am having a go at pgSQL for the first time.

Many thanks in advance indeed - Eugen

#### The problem I like to solve

I like to return an array of words with a minimum length from a text. Picked `regexp_matches` which returns `SETOF text[]` (not array). There may be better ways but this is what I picked.

```
regexp_matches ( string text, pattern text [, flags text ] ) → setof text[]
```

- [Postgres Reference for String functins](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-string.html)

#### The Issue

When trying to use individual results from the resut set (seemingly arrays) they are in fact of type `text` but include the curly brackets of a Postgres array.

### Example

Functionally the below example works because I added a workaround removing curly brackets with the `trim` function.

#### The output for the function described below

```sql
# select lower_words_arr('there is an answer','\w{3,}') AS words;
NOTICE:  match = {there}
NOTICE:  match = {answer}
     words      
----------------
 {there,answer}
(1 row)
```

#### My Question

Why come, that individual `regexp_matches` entries match and return data as `"{txt}"` but behave as type text and not ARRAY?

Is there a way without my workaround?

#### Code

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION lower_words_arr(input_str text, match_expr text) RETURNS text[] AS $$
DECLARE
    words_arr text[];
    one_match text;
BEGIN
    FOR one_match IN SELECT regexp_matches(lower(input_str), match_expr, 'g') 
    AS match 
    LOOP
        RAISE NOTICE 'match = %', one_match;

        -- But if I write:
        --
        -- RAISE NOTICE 'match = %', one_match[0];
        --
        -- fails with:
        ---
        -- ERROR:  cannot subscript type text because it is not an array
        -- CONTEXT:  SQL statement "SELECT one_match[0]"
        -- PL/pgSQL function lower_words_arr(text,text) line 10 at RAISE
        --
        -- even though this the result returned
        ---
        -- NOTICE:  match = {there}
        -- NOTICE:  match = {answewr}

        words_arr := array_append(words_arr,trim(BOTH '{}' FROM one_match));
    END LOOP;

    RETURN words_arr;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Could it be the **SELECT** that's doing this? Try just `FOR one_match IN regexp_matches(lower(input_str), match_expr, 'g')`

Comment: Many thanks Don very much appreciate your thought, Postgres raises a syntax error without the SELECT 

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "regexp_matches"
LINE 6:     FOR one_match IN regexp_matches(lower(input_str), match_... 

But I think I am closing in on the case - always interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Declare `one_match` not as `text`, but `text[]`.

Answer (score 1):

We were able to achieve the array-like behavior using:

```
DECLARE
  _match text[];
BEGIN
  FOR _match IN SELECT REGEXP_MATCHES(_msg, '@\[(.*?)]\((.*?)\)' , 'g') LOOP
    RAISE NOTICE '%', _match[2];
  END LOOP;

  RETURN;
END;
```

Test String (in this case, `_msg`): `Hello, @[Test User](12345) and @[Second User](67890)!`

Edit: here's a full working demo with a function definition

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_matches(_test_str text)  
  RETURNS VOID 
  LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
  AS $FUNCTION$

DECLARE
  _match text[];
BEGIN
  FOR _match IN SELECT REGEXP_MATCHES(_test_str, '@\[(.*?)]\((.*?)\)' , 'g') LOOP
    RAISE NOTICE '%', _match;
  END LOOP;

  RETURN;
END;

$FUNCTION$;

SELECT get_matches('Hello, @[Test User](12345) and @[Second User](67890)!');
```

```
psql:test.sql:18: NOTICE:  {"Test User",12345}
psql:test.sql:18: NOTICE:  {"Second User",67890}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have now solved the issue without the `trim` workaround. The solution came right from the [Postgres documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-matching.html). Look for `SELECT (regexp_match('foobarbequebaz', 'bar.*que'))[1];` on that page. With that knowledge in hand I changed the function to

#### Improved Solution

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION lower_words_arr(input_str text, match_expr text) RETURNS text[] AS $$
DECLARE
    words_arr text[];
    one_match text;
BEGIN
    FOR one_match IN SELECT(regexp_matches(lower(input_str), match_expr, 'g'))[1] AS match 
    LOOP
        RAISE NOTICE 'match = %', one_match;
        words_arr := array_append(words_arr,one_match);
    END LOOP;

    RETURN words_arr;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql STABLE;
```

#### Output

```
select lower_words_arr('there is an answer - you will find it in the Postgres documentation.','\w{4,}') AS words;
NOTICE:  match = there
NOTICE:  match = answer
NOTICE:  match = will
NOTICE:  match = find
NOTICE:  match = postgres
NOTICE:  match = documentation
                      words                      
-------------------------------------------------
 {there,answer,will,find,postgres,documentation}
(1 row)
```

#### Conclusion

My original problem has been solved, but a puzzling piece understanding is still missing (not subject of my initial question):

- Why does the `one_match` variable not behave like an array when `[1]` is removed from the SELECT?

Maybe I should open a question specific to that behaviour ...